# Solr query by specific fields

Tags: solr

I use solr , latest version.
I run text query with "OR" condition by different fields.
I want to have indication due to which field the document return.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to specify which fields do you want to get back in the response, then you're after the `fl` parameter, if you do a request like:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/demo/query?
  q=title_t:black
  fl=author,title
```

You're indicating that you only want to get back the author and title fields, something like:

```js
{"response":{"numFound":2,"start":0,"docs":[
    {
      "title":"The Black Company",
      "author":"Glen Cook"},
    {
      "title":"The Black Cauldron",
      "author":"Lloyd Alexander"}]
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Faceting could be an option here. In your Solr Query set "facet" to true. You also need to set "facet.field" to the fields that you are including in OR search criteria. The Solr Response will then show you how many results are returned for each of the search fields.

Here is the reference - https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Faceting

-Amit

Comment: But This doesn't help me. For example , I have 100 results, I must have ability to say in which field include the searching word in every document.